# How do I use VBA to save my PowerPoint as a read only PDF file?

Tags: vba, pdf, powerpoint

I have my code that saves my file as a .pdf that works great, but I want it to be saved as read-only as well.

```
Dim FilePath as String
With Application.ActivePresentation
    .SaveCopyAs FilePath & "CurrentBrief.pdf". ppSaveasPDF
End With
```

I am using PowerPoint 2016 and am looking for what I can add/change to make this code add the read-only attribute to my PDF file.

Comment: Do you mean read-only as in "the read-only operating system attribute is set" or as in "password protect the PDF"?  If the former, SetAttr "C:\temp\yourfile.pptx",vbReadOnly   If the latter, I don't think it's possible.

Comment: The SetAttr worked to do what I wanted it to, Thank you Steve!